# Get the Short Date Format from users device or browser in React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am working with reactjs and material UI datepicker. I need to pass the short date format to the datepicker component (e.g. `format="MM/dd/yyyy"`). Also using the built-in date validation, I want to make this format dynamic and based on the user's preferred format in the device (windows, mac, ios, android) or the browser. Is there a way to get the date format in react? Either through a library or pure JavaScript?

*i.e. I'm using `i18next` for translation handling. Not sure if there's any function for handling date format as well. This is my first time working with this concept.*

Answer (score 0):

i18next has a format function you can use to do whatever you want: https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/formatting

Comment: This format function formats the date as far as I understand from the link. But in my app the formatting is done by the datepicker component. I only need to pass the correct date format according to the user's device settings.